# Do we need to place two sqlite files for two different tables in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on android applications. In my project I kept my sqlite file(which contains only one table) in assets folder and it is working fine. But when I created two tables in it and kept the same file in assets folder it is not recognizing the other table when I wrote the query with the other table. **It is displaying the error as unable to find the table**
    How to use the other table? Please help me regarding this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need a single DB. Give your project a clean. _Project > Clean_